# Sql Between Dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to do a sql query to get data in a clause in between. The problems, is that i dont know how to do a query who can have differences clause between depends on the value in the parameter.

What i have:

```
SELECT TableA.DNSName, TableA.IPAddressStr, TableB.OSName
FROM TableB 
INNER JOIN TableA 
  ON TableB.AssetOSID = TableA.AssetOSID 
CROSS JOIN IPRanges
WHERE (IpRanges.ConfigID = @configID)
  (Assets.IPAddress BETWEEN IPRanges.StartIPAddress AND IPRanges.EndIPAddress)
```

what table look like:

```
IpRanges:
ConfigID|StartIpAdress|EndIPAdress <br>
1|23|53
1|56|87
3|90|134
3|560|600 
3|780|800
```

As you can see the number of ipRanges changes on each configID and theres is no link between the table ipRanges And the table TableA.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At first glance you're missing an AND statement between you where clause criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're after here.. Some sample results along with sample data from other tables would help..

But this may be close.

```
SELECT TableA.DNSName, TableA.IPAddressStr, TableB.OSName 
FROM TableB 
INNER JOIN TableA 
  ON TableB.AssetOSID = TableA.AssetOSID 
INNER JOIN IPRanges 
  ON (IpRanges.ConfigID = @configID)
 AND (Assets.IPAddress BETWEEN IPRanges.StartIPAddress AND IPRanges.EndIPAddress)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it woks fine and really fast.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to use aggregation with a `having` clause -- because you want all the conditions to be true.

The idea is to count the number of times the ranges are true and compare them to the total count:

```
SELECT TableA.DNSName, TableA.IPAddressStr, TableB.OSName
FROM TableB INNER JOIN
     TableA
     ON TableB.AssetOSID = TableA.AssetOSID CROSS JOIN
     IPRanges
WHERE (IpRanges.ConfigID = @configID)
group by TableA.DNSName, TableA.IPAddressStr, TableB.OSName
having sum(case when Assets.IPAddress BETWEEN IPRanges.StartIPAddress AND IPRanges.EndIPAddress) then 1 else 0 end) =
       count(*);
```

If only one of the rows needs to match, then use this `having` clause:

```
having sum(case when Assets.IPAddress BETWEEN IPRanges.StartIPAddress AND IPRanges.EndIPAddress) then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```